# Big Catholic events, where are the questions?

Tags: discussion, catholicism

Pretty depressing to have so few Catholicism questions when so much is going on. I kind of think that's because people don't think to go here and ask about current events - which are definitely topical.

Anyway, now would be a good time to [Sign up for Catholic Culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88300/catholic-culture-ministry-and-apologetics) or ask them here.  I'd like to see what other people think about the Pope and the World Meeting of Families and hear what questions they have!  There are Catholics standing by to take your questions...

Comment: Believe me - I'd love to ask some of these questions, but I'm afraid that the close vote police would abruptly close them.

Comment: Maybe I just haven't been following the news enough, but if there was anything I was curious about I'd definitely ask it

Comment: What kinds of questions are you expecting/hoping for?

Comment: @Flimzy anything - the Pope said a lot of things that needed clarification, a lot that went way over my head.

Answer (score 6):

The [Catholic Culture proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88300/catholic-culture-ministry-and-apologetics) holds some promise and I'd like it to succeed. If that interests you please do go sign up for it. **But...**

> I'd like to see what other people think about _____.

**...don't expect this.** Stack Exchange sites just aren't cut out to service that desire. The patterns that make for effective questions an answers in which people get solid answers to specific questions and then move on to their next problem doesn't mesh with patterns that *develop* ideas through discussion and the injection of opinions.

If what you want is to find out what other people are thinking about current events, you should look for a more classical forum format. If you want high quality software to go with that format that will help keep the community stay a cut above the noise you should look into something powered by [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) or similar well thought out discussion platforms rather than the clumsy 'bulletin board' genre of software.

Comment: Im not saying I want to "start a conversation" I'm just saying I am a bit saddened by the lack of curiosity. You can find out more about what people are paying attention to when they ask questions about it because it means they are actively listening.

Comment: @PeterTurner That's true enough, but that's not what the question sounded like to me, hence the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's an image I've seen shared a few times. Maybe we could workshop together a question based on it.

[image: Criticisms of the Pope's speech to the US Congress]

Potential questions:

- Are there Catholics who have been critical of this speech too (too broad?)
- Does the Pope/the Vatican have guidelines which give him reasons to not discuss these topics in certain situations, so that we shouldn't have expected him to discuss these things in this recent speech?
- Are there specific reasons why it would be inappropriate for the Pope to pray in congress?
- Has Pope Francis previously spoken/written in affirmation of humanist philosophy?

Any other ideas?